# Errors in the creation of a new Laravel project, using composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I created a laravel project using this composer command create-project laravel / laravel --prefer-dist then opened the project in netbeans and the project contains errors.

One of the errors is class_with_method_that_declares_anonymous_class

`$ O = new class {public function foo () {}};`

Another bug is in the ReportSpecificationstarts file, among others.

Does anyone know why this happens?